# Prove using induction or strong induction.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction

Let the sequence $G_0, G_1, G_2, . . .$ be defined recursively as follows:
$G_0 = 0, G_1 = 1$, and $$G_n = (5 G_{n-1}) − (6 G_{n-2})$$ for every n belongs to N, n ≥ 2.

Prove using induction or strong induction that for all n belongs to N, $G_n = 3^n − 2^n$.

Comment: Did you meant $ G_n = 3^n - 2^n $

Comment: @Nilanjan Yes. Edited it.

Comment: What have you done so far?  Have you checked the base case(s)?  What does the inductive case translate to?

Comment: Yes, the Base Case for 2 is true.

Comment: Hint: replace $G_{n-1}$ and $G_{n-2}$ in the recurrence relation with the inductive hypothesis, and then work out the algebra from there!

Comment: @DhruvSomani the base cases are actually $0, 1$.

Comment: @Colm Bhandal You see that $n>=2$. And anyway its a recursive series and the values for $G_0$ and $G_1$ are already provided.

Comment: @DhruvSomani the $n\geq2$ only applies to the recurrence relation, not the condition you are trying to prove. Do you see why we need $n\geq2$ for the recurrence?

Comment: @ Colm Bhandal The values for $G_0$ and $G_1$ are already provided.

Comment: Any idea how to begin with the inductive step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First, show that this is true for $n=0,1$:**

$G_0=3^0-2^0$

$G_1=3^1-2^1$

**Second, assume that this is true for all $k \leq n$:**

$G_0=3^0-2^0$

$G_1=3^1-2^1$

$\dots$

$G_{n-1}=3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$

$G_n=3^n-2^n$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$G_{n+1}=$

$5\cdot\color\red{G_n}-6\cdot\color\green{G_{n-1}}=$

$5\cdot(\color\red{3^n-2^n})-6\cdot(\color\green{3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}})=$

$5\cdot3^n-5\cdot2^n-2\cdot3^n+3\cdot2^n=$

$3\cdot3^n-2\cdot2^n=$

$3^{n+1}-2^{n+1}$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the parts marked red and green.

Comment: Minor detail: since the recurrence relation is second order, you need to do $n=0,1$ as base cases, and then for the induction assume that it is true for both $n$ and $n-1$ to prove that it is true for $n+1$. Otherwise the steps marked in green are not permitted.

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks for pointing that out, I have updated accordingly (and in addition, used strong induction in a more explicit manner).

Comment: You've used strong induction over here?

Comment: @DhruvSomani: I have, but I think that in the original answer, I did so rather implicitly. I have now updated the answer to make it more explicit.

Comment: Yeah. I understand it now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Prove its true for G(2), and write G(k+1) in terms of G(k) and G(k-1), G(k) and G(k-1) both satisfy $ 3^n - 2^n $, substitute and solve.